# c program list accessing value segmentation fault

Tags: c, list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_struct {
    int data;
    struct node_struct *next;
} node;

typedef node *list;


int main()
{
    int temp;
    list head , tempList;
    char cont = 'Y';
    head = NULL;

    do {
        printf("Enter Data\n");
        scanf("%d",&temp); fflush(stdin);
        tempList = (list)malloc(sizeof(node));
        tempList->data = temp;
        tempList->next = head->next; // This line has error
        head->next = tempList;
        printf("Do you wish to continue (Y/N)\n");
        scanf("%c", &cont); fflush(stdin);
    } while (cont == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048516 in main () at listself.c:24

I want to point head pointer to the latest input value . but head->next gives me segmentation fault .

**My question is how I can implement this logic ?**

```
user input 1 : 5
user input 2 : 6
user input 3 : 3
```

and the internal structure of list be like

**head -> 3 -> 6 -> 5**

Also the while loop just exits before taking in the value for cont . propably it takes in "\n" . Any solution for that ?

Comment: `head->next` is the address of no where as head itself is null and then you are assigning it to templist->next .

Comment: Please let me know , how can I initialize head->next to NULL in the above code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head is only a pointer and is not pointing to any memory so you cannot dereference it.

First you have to set the ->next value of tempList to NULL.

```
tempList->next = NULL ;
```

Then you have to change the way you use head.

```
tempList->next = head; // point it to NULL or the head
head = tempList;  // tempList becomes the new head
```

Comment: Yes , but if I do that then if the user inputs 5,6,3 then my internal structure will be like 5 -> 6 -> 3 -> head ? right ?

Comment: @yantrakaar No, it will be exactly reversed. head->3->6...  And note that head is just a pointer, while the others are structures.

Comment: can you comment on this ? Also the while loop just exits before taking in the value for cont . probably it takes in "\n" . Any solution for that ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to allocate `head` before you refer to it.

Also, you need to set `head->next` to a value before you set `tempList->next` to `head->next`.

So...

```
head = (list)malloc(sizeof(node));
tempList = (list)malloc(sizeof(node));
head->next = NULL;
head->next = tempList;
tempList->data = temp;
```

Comment: exactly +1 , quite fast an answer :)

Comment: Exactly , I am asking on how can I initialize head->next to NULL so that the programs works properly .

Comment: can you comment on this ? Also the while loop just exits before taking in the value for cont . probably it takes in "\n" . Any solution for that ?

Comment: Thanks , since user2501 has more appropriate answer to my question I have selected his as answer . I will up vote yours as well .

Answer (score 0):

You set head to null so of course you will get a segfault. You need to init head like you do tmpList.